# one input class, only modify empty ones

Tags: javascript, jquery, if-statement, for-loop

I have this code, that makes all input fields named "inputix" having a red border if there is one empty, i would like to change only the ones that are empty:

html part http://pastebin.com/4kyv8dLD

```
for (i=0;i<required.length;i++) {
    var input = $('#'+required[i]);
    if ((input.attr('value') === "") || (input.val() === emptyerror)) {
        input.addClass("needsfilled");
    } else {
        input.removeClass("needsfilled");
    }
}

if (!/^([a-zA-Z0-9_.-])+@(([a-zA-Z0-9-])+.)+([a-zA-Z0-9]{2,4})+$/.test(email.val())) {
    email.addClass("needsfilled");
    email.val(emailerror);
}


if ($(":input").hasClass("needsfilled")) {
    i=0;
    $('.inputix').css('border','solid 1px red');
    for (i=0; i<5; i++){
        $('.inputix'+[i]).css('border','solid 1px red');
    }
    return true;
}
```

The problem is that only want the empty ones to get red borders...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

there is no need to use a `for` loop, you can use [`start with`](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-starts-with-selector/) selector:

> Selects elements that have the specified attribute with a value beginning exactly with a given string.

```
$('input[class^="inputix"]').css('border','solid 1px red')
```

as an alternative you can use an `each` loop:

```
$('form').submit(function(){
    $('input').each(function(){
        if (this.value == '') {
           $(this).addClass('error')
        } else {
            $(this).removeClass('error')  
        }
    })

    if ($('input.error').length > 0) {
        return false
    }           
})
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/yZgAg/)

Comment: Don't understand, the first for loop checks if any field is empty

The second for for loop, runs all the different inputix classes , inputix1 , inputix2, inputix3, because i changed the inputs css's, they are different

Comment: @Souza okay, you can use `start with` selector, try the updated answer.

Comment: Now that makes sense! Thank you very much. But remains the problem of having all fields red, instead of the empty ones

Comment: @Souza you are welcome, have you tried the jQuery [`each`](http://api.jquery.com/each/) method?

Comment: @Souza using `each` method will simplify the task that you are doing, can you post the html?

Comment: Thank you very much, i haven't used the each function, too bad it does not run over all the elements at once